# Solving the recurrence relation $x\to\frac{Kx}{x+(K-x)e^{-r}}+M$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

Suppose that $x_0$ is given and
$$
x_n=\frac{Kx_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}+(K-x_{n-1})e^{-r}}+M,\qquad\text{ for }n\geq1
$$
where $K$, $r$, and $M$ are real constants. How can I find a general formula for $x_n$?

### Context

Suppose that the initial population of a country is $x_0$, then the population of the country at time $t$, where $t$ is in years, is given by the logistic model

$$
x=\frac{Kx_0}{x_0+(K-x_0)e^{-rt}}
$$
The logistic model does not include the immigration to the country. If we assume that on average $M$ people immigrate to the country each year, then how can we modify the logistic model so that it includes immigration to the country as well?

Comment: Surely you must have hit this relation somewhere in your work. You can edit your question to include this context.

Comment: Have you tried iterating it?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel : I have added the context too.

Comment: @smcc : I did but the algebra gets very messy.

Comment: Why can't you use $x = x_0e^{rt}$ for the growth formula?

Comment: @ArukaJ : Well, that becomes too easy. This is not my choice to choose the growth model, unfortunately.

Comment: Thus, $x_{n+1}=\frac{ax_n+b}{cx_n+d}$ for some given constants $(a,b,c,d)$. To iterate this homographic function, look for its fixed points $u$ and $v$ and consider the reduced variable $y_n=\frac{x_n-u}{x_n-v}$, then the transformation $y_n\to y_{n+1}$ is quite simple, iterating it is trivial, and all this answers your question.

Comment: Your difference equation at the top looks like the *solution* to a *differential* equation like $\frac{dx}{dt}=rx(1-x)$ (i.e. the logistic growth model). It seems you are mixing up continuous and discrete time models and the solution with he difference equation. Is this an equation you came up with?

Comment: The growth model is continuous but if you want to add $M$ immigrants, perhaps it should also be treated as a continuous growth as well, because right now it seems like you're just appending it at the end of each time period (mixing together continuous and discrete models)

Comment: @ArukaJ : What do you suggest?

Comment: @smcc : Yes, the very first equation is something I came up with. Given my context, how would you modify the logistic model to include immigration too?

Comment: What does $K$ represent?

Comment: @ArukaJ : carrying capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard logistic growth model in discrete time is

$$N_{t+1}=N_t+rN_t\left(1-\frac{N_t}{K}\right)$$

where $N_t$ is the population at time $t$, $r$ is the natural growth rate, and $K$ is the carrying capacity.

To add immigration of amount $M$ each period just write:

$$N_{t+1}=N_t+rN_t\left(1-\frac{N_t}{K}\right)+M$$

However there is no closed form solution to this.

---

The standard logistic growth model in continuous time is

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=rN\left(1-\frac{N}{K}\right).$$

This has a nice closed form solution:

$$N(t)=\frac{K}{1+\left(\frac{K}{N_0}-1\right)e^{-rt}}$$

With constant immigration rate $M$ you would have

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=rN\left(1-\frac{N}{K}\right)+M$$

This has a closed form solution similar to the standard logistic growth model. You can find the solution in this paper here (as well as an extension to a stochastic model):

http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tpb.2003.08.003

Comment: And... about the question actually asked?

Comment: I think you are missing an $N$ in your last two equations after $r$.

Comment: You answered my actual question. I can not upvote because I do not have enough votes to be able to do that. I will accept your answer when the system allows me. and I did not downvote it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Did The equation in the question did not make sense given the application (you might have realized this if you read the question after OP added the context). The OP seems to be happy with the answer.

Comment: "You answered my actual question" HUH? Yet another mse mystery, I guess.

Comment: @Did Did you read the bit below the heading "Context": "The logistic model does not include the immigration to the country. If we assume that on average $M$ people immigrate to the country each year, then how can we modify the logistic model so that it includes immigration to the country as well?"

Comment: Sure I did (you know what, I do not comment before reading). And it does not correspond to the math part and the math part can be answered but this seems to be one of these occasions when what is asked is not what is asked. All this is too Lewiscarollian for me, I am afraid, but kudos for your deciphering abilities.